# Rails ActiveRecord: Query a many-to-many association with a where on the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

So I have three models, User, Course, and Registration. There is a many to many association between User and Course through Registration.

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :registrations
  has_many :users, through: :registrations
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :registrations
  has_many :courses, through: :registrations
end
```

Real simple stuff, and everything works how it is supposed to, but there is also a field in registrations which I would like to base my queries off of. There is a "role" field in registrations, and I would like to sometimes select all people in a certain course with a certain role. Currently I do that in two queries, is there a way to do this in  a single query?

Here is what I currently do:

```
course = Course.find(1)
registration = course.registrations.where(role: "some_role").limit(1)[0]
user = registration.user
```

As you can see this would be three queries, is there a way to combine the last two call so that there is only one SQL query for those two in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. Here is how:

```
@course = Course.find_by_access_code(params[:access_code])
@instructor = @course.users.where("registrations.role = ?", 'instructor').limit(1)[0]
```

This does what I wanted it to do, shorten the 3 SQL queries into 2.

Thanks anyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
user = Registration.includes(:user).find_by(role: 'some_role', course:course).user
```

The problem with this query is that if there is no such registration, it will raise an exception. So, either you need to handle the exception, or guarantee that the registration exists.

I don't think handling the exception is a very clean approach. An extra DB call may not affect performance, but will make the code easier to read and test.

To reduce the number of queries, you will need to eager load the user. See [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). This is similar to the N+1 problem.

Alternately, you may want to do

```
course = Course.find(1)
registration = course.registrations.find_by(role: "some_role")
user = registration.user if registration
```

If you don't need the course, you can do:

```
registration = Registration.find_by(course_id: 1, role: "some_role")
user = registration.user if registration
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my question though does it? There are still three queries here, the first is not in your code, that is the one to get the course. The second is a find on the registration database, and the third is the ".user" call, which would make another database query, I believe.

Comment: `includes` prevents the third DB call. I was just showing a way of doing it without handing the exception.

Comment: There many to many relations so Registration.find_by(course_id: 1, role: "some_role") return an array of object..

Comment: The `includes` does not reduce the number of queries. Just tested it.

Comment: Hey @BSeven I think I was not clear in what I wanted in the question, but I found my own solution. You can see it below.